# IOS7 UIModalPresentationPageSheet Issue

Tags: ios, ios5, ios7

I need to set the position for my Modal popup. Its working fine lesser than IOS 7 only problem with  IOS 7. I could not able to set coordinate of the Modal Popup. Its not taking the any values.

```
MyModalViewController *targetController = [[[MyModalViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
targetController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; 
[self presentModalViewController:targetController animated:YES];
targetController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(40, 80, 944, 650);
```

Comment: Some code or image would be helpful.

Comment: @Piyush added the sample code check...